# How install custom branding module in openmrs?

Tags: java, maven, openmrs

I followed all the steps for installing OpenMRS. I downloaded the OpenMRS core source code and then executed  mvn clean install  in console. Then execute the command mvn jetty: run in the webapp directory and everything worked right. So, I downloaded  the custom brading 0.2(.omod) module from openmrs modules repository and I copied this in .../Application Data/OpenMRS/modules and then execute mvn jetty:run for launch. I get the following errors:

```
ERROR - Listener.performWebStartOfModules(651) |2015-10-19 09:17:50,233| Unable to refresh the spring application context.  Root Cause was:
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.springframework.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.openmrs.module.ModuleUtil.refreshApplicationContext(ModuleUtil.java:842)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.WebModuleUtil.refreshWAC(WebModuleUtil.java:953)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.performWebStartOfModules(Listener.java:638)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.performWebStartOfModules(Listener.java:617)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.startOpenmrs(Listener.java:255)
    at org.openmrs.web.WebDaemon$1.run(WebDaemon.java:42)
WARN - Listener.performWebStartOfModules(680) |2015-10-19 09:17:50,249| caught another error: 
org.openmrs.api.APIException: Service not found: interface org.openmrs.scheduler.SchedulerService
    at org.openmrs.api.context.ServiceContext.getService(ServiceContext.java:700)
    at org.openmrs.api.context.ServiceContext.getSchedulerService(ServiceContext.java:291)
    at org.openmrs.api.context.Context.getSchedulerService(Context.java:498)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.WebModuleUtil.stopTasks(WebModuleUtil.java:378)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.WebModuleUtil.stopModule(WebModuleUtil.java:852)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.WebModuleUtil.shutdownModules(WebModuleUtil.java:795)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.performWebStartOfModules(Listener.java:657)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.performWebStartOfModules(Listener.java:617)
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.startOpenmrs(Listener.java:255)
    at org.openmrs.web.WebDaemon$1.run(WebDaemon.java:42)
```

anyone knows it could be?
Note: My internet connection is behind proxy and the commands of maven worked because I set the proxy in the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your system connected to the internet?

Also, it's not clear if you've downloaded and run a released version of OpenMRS, or if you just grabbed the latest (under development) code from GitHub. Can you please clarify?

Finally, you may get more responses from OpenMRS experts than you'll get here, by using the project's own Q&A site: https://talk.openmrs.org/c/ask

Comment: I Just grabbed the latest (under development) code from GitHub and this code has problems. Thank you